# WebBrowser on Linux Ubuntu [C#]

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono, webbrowser-control

I've written an simple bot that run through certain site, login, check stuff and so on. For this purpose I've used C#, and WebBrowser that's in System.Windows.Forms.

Now I want to run that app on my Ubuntu server so it will be constantly running. The first problem was how to a run Web Browser in a console app, but then I implemented Win.Forms References and it went well on Windows. So I moved on to Ubuntu. I've installed mono, compile the program with win.forms reference : : : : : : : : `gmcs program.cs -r:System.Windows.Forms.dll`, everything went well but when I run that app big random errors showed up. (When initializing new Web Browser object to be exact). I've read about Mono Firefox Browser but I don't know how to properly implement it on Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what the errors were?

Comment: Do you need to use a console web-browser ? Have you had a look at selenium or even phantom.js? Might be easier to implement.

Comment: Here you go, full error code: http://imgur.com/EOoZgqV

I need an browser that I can easly navigate through sites, invoke objects (such as buttons), read site source and use cookies (when I log in I need to stay log in).

Comment: You can use spec flow to simulate the test you are trying to do